# Lumia 540 unresponsive

Tags: lock-screen, lumia-540

My Lumia 540 has just frozen. I slide to open but it is not responding.

Comment: Have you tried performing a soft reset? [See here for instructions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d).

Comment: I tried that and tried using Windows Device Recovery Tool bu to no avail. i finally did a hard reset. And it worked. Manay things got erased and I am working to reset or install them.

Answer (score -1):

I did a hard reset and it woked.